# Prevent xsltproc / XSLT from un-escaping unicode hex characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to pre-process some editor-generated xml files before checking them into github, in order to sort some elements so that textual diffs will work correctly (Yes, I know there are XML-compare tools, but most I found are a little costly and a bit overboard for what I need to do).

However, there's a different issue - which is that the default XML (which is output by Pentaho Kettle) has Unicode hex encodings. However, once I run even a simple transform through `xsltproc` (I also tried with `Saxon`), it un-escapes them.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <name>test</name>
    <server>&#x24;&#x7b;name1&#x7d;</server>
    <type>MYSQL</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>&#x24;&#x7b;dbname&#x7d;</database>
    <port>3306</port>
    <username>&#x24;&#x7b;user&#x7d;</username>
    <password>&#x24;&#x7b;password&#x7d;</password>
</top>
```

turns into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="uft-8"?>
<top>
    <name>test</name>
    <server>${name1}</server>
    <type>MYSQL</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>${dbname}</database>
    <port>3306</port>
    <username>${user}</username>
    <password>${password}</password>
</top>
```

when using this simple (dummy) transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've seen other questions where people have asked how to unencode such characters, but in my case, I want to *prevent* it from happening. I will eventually add some sorting instructions to this transform, but for now I'd like to sort out this issue. The Spoon/Kettle tool will continually re-escape these characters so I'd like to avoid many lines of diffs even for a minor change.

**Further explanation**

The ultimate goal is to sort part of an xml document that is generated by a graphical editor. The sorting is being done to minimize diffs and make it easier for developers to understand what was changed using simple diff tools - even if the editor, when saving, reorders certain elements. Thus, I'd rather not touch anything else - Kettle may have reasons for doing this (seemingly useless) encoding, and I'd like to keep their format as is, if at all possible. Thus, what I'd really like to do is turn something like this:

```
<top>
  <server>&#x24;&#x7b;name1&#x7d;</server>
  <step>
     <name>x</name>
     <type>z</type>
  </step>
  <step>
     <name>a</name>
     <type>b</type>
  </step>
  <another>
     <name>Z</name>
     <foo>bar</foo>
  </another>
  <another>
     <name>A</name>
     <foo>silly</foo>
  </another>
</top>
```

into

```
<top>
  <server>&#x24;&#x7b;name1&#x7d;</server>
  <step>
     <name>a</name>
     <type>b</type>
  </step>
  <step>
     <name>x</name>
     <type>z</type>
  </step>
  <another>
     <name>Z</name>
     <foo>bar</foo>
  </another>
  <another>
     <name>A</name>
     <foo>silly</foo>
  </another>
</top>
```

e.g. sort the `step` elements by `name`, in place, without touching anything else. I'm still working on that, and may end up coming back to the Stack for help there :) In any case, I've done this sorting with other XML files successfully using XSLT, so was trying the same approach here.

Comment: You need to understand that an XSLT processor usually works together with an XML parser which parses the XML first into a tree structure of nodes which does not store any character references but simply characters. So within XSLT you can't preserve any character references. What you can try to enforce some reescaping is using a different output encoding like `encoding="US-ASCII"`. But that would then escape all non-ASCII characters in the result, not those characters that were originally escaped.

Comment: @MartinHonnen US-ASCII wouldn't even force the changes wanted, since they're all US-ASCII range characters.

Comment: I've tried encoding as ascii, but it doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason for doing this, but you haven't explained it. You're more likely to get a helpful answer if you make it clear that you know this is a ridiculous requirement, but you need to do it for some good reason.

Comment: added more explanation above...

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for how to turn XML into absolutely identical XML using an XML tool.

This doesn't make a lot of sense, such tools can't even see the difference.

You'll have to drop down to a lower level. Since these particular characters aren't name characters this is straight-forward because you don't have to check that you aren't accidentally mangling a name by escaping in a context where that isn't allowed.

Write a script that reads in the file as text, replaces the characters in question, and spits them out again.

All that said, I'd suggest that you normalise the other way: The second example is much more readable than the first, and there's no good reason why `&#x24;`, `&#x7b;` or `&#x7d;` should ever appear in an XML file. If you could take the hurt of committing something that changed all of those files, then you might find that the output of your tool was only rarely different in ways that weren't a real diff, or failing that that using Canonical XML sufficed to get rid of any such cases where text differences weren't XML differences.

Comment: I agree, in that I'd love to have the xml cleaner. The problem is, every time we open the file in the spoon editor, it will re-escape all of those characters, and then if we compare what is on disk to the repo, it will show lots of changes that aren't really changes. While I realize the current transform doesn't actually *do* anything, I am in the process of writing a transform that will sort certain elements, which is why I'm using XSLT - but perhaps you're right I need to go down a level in the toolstack...

Comment: Can you fix the spoon editor? Even if you still need an escaping-normalising step on the other, it'd probably make life easier.

Comment: Spoon is by Pentaho - not sure if I want to get into changing the editor just to solve this problem... I don't know why they are encoding like that, they presumably have a reason...